# Checking a key exists in a Dictionary of Action's before trying to call it using ForEach

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dictionary where the key is a string and the value is an Action. I setup mapping of string keys to functions. I then have a list that I call .ForEach() on and inside this I use a value in the list as the key and then call the function associated with it. The issue will come if the key doesn't exist. How can I check this in the .ForEach function? I'd like to use the ternary operator but it doesn't seem to work.

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<IniConfig, object>> typeMapping = new Dictionary<string, Func<IniConfig, object>>();

typeMapping["MB"] = ProcessMB;

public object ProcessMB(IniConfig file)
{
    return null;
}

object iif(bool expression, object truePart, object falsePart)
    { return expression ? truePart : falsePart; }

FilesToProcess.ForEach(x => iif(typeMapping.ContainsKey(x.ExtractType), typeMapping[x.ExtractType](x), Error(x)));
```

This highlights the 2nd parameter in the iif() call with error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object', and the same thing for the Error(x) part.

So it seems like the ternary operator returns an object? So if I change my Action to a Func and have the return type be object and make my functions return object it compiles, but when I run a test with an invalid key it doesn't go into my Error() function it throws "The given key was not present in the dictionary" exception. I would expect it to do the ternary operation and see that typeMapping doesn't have the key and so fail to the Error() function. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just do  `FilesToProcess.Where(x=>typeMapping.ContainsKey(x.ExtractType)).ForEach(condition)` to filter out the missing keys first?

Comment: Additionally, it looks like Error(x) is a function you've defined somewhere.  If I understand your code correctly, you're just calling it in the ForEach(), and I'm assuming that `Error()` returns `void`?  In that case, it might help to specify that you want an action, so replace Error(x) with `()=>{Error(x);}`

Comment: Your `iif` is not a real ternary operator, it's just a method call. So its parameters are being calculated before call to `iif`. That's why you are getting an exception. Of course, you can avoid it by passing `Func<object>`, but, as others pointed, there are better ways to solve your problem

Comment: I like this solution, but could I get the Error() method called in this one call if the key doesn't exist? I mean I could make another call after I guess which negates the ContainsKey() and then call Error() just curious if it can be done in 1 call/chain.

Comment: `TryGetValue()` is meant for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `iif()` method is counter-intuitive here, and it seems like an over-use of LINQ. Here is what I would do:

```
foreach (var file in filesToProcess)
{
    Func<IniConfig, object> action;
    if (typeMapping.TryGetValue(file.ExtractType, out action))
    {
        action(file);
    }
    else
    {
        Error(file);
    }
}
```

Makes your code easier to read too :)

**Edit:**

I Have found a generic way to do what you want. First you need to create an extension method for `IDictionary<TKey,TVal>` that simply returns the default value if a key does not exist:

```
public static TVal GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TVal>(this IDictionary<TKey, TVal> self, TKey key)
{
    TVal ret;
    self.TryGetValue(key, out ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Then you can use the null coalescing (`??`) operator:

```
FilesToProcess.ForEach((typeMapping.GetValueOrDefault(x.ExtractType) ?? Error)(x));
```

Comment: The iif can go but I like the ternary operator (I was just trying an alternative way of making the ternary operator work with the iff) and if that was able to be inline I think it's plenty easy to read. Checking keys before access is such a common thing it would be nice if it was streamlined in some way.

Comment: @user441521 Ok, but the `TryGetValue()` method is for this exact purpose.

Comment: And it requires making another variable and wrapping an if statement and not working in ForEach() as far as I know. Not as streamlined in my view, but it is what it is. foreach it is.

Comment: Perhaps something about this idea can become more generic and an extension to Dictionaries. Not exactly what you have but I'm thinking there must be a way to check the key and if not exist call a function and if does exist return it's value which we then can do something with. It's not 100% coming to me yet exactly how to do that but something like:

dict.OnError(Error(x)).Try(x.KeyToTry)(x);

or something. I'm thinking in very javascript terms here.

Comment: @user441521 I figured out what you mean. See my edited answer.

Comment: That's what I'm after, but I'll take that one step further and have 2 Action's passed in. The first one will be where you access the dictionary using the key and I'll try/catch that and if it fails call the 2nd Action which will be the error message. That should be a built-in dictionary function if you ask me.

Comment: I got this working but can we streamline it in a generic way more do you think: FilesToProcess.ForEach(x =>
                typeMapping.Try(x.ExtractType,
                    x,
                    (z) => typeMapping[x.ExtractType](x),
                    (z) => Error(x)
                )
            );

Answer (score 2):

Make your life easy and just create a little helper function that does what you want:

```
private void InvokeProcessor(IniConfig iniConfig)
{
    Func<IniConfig, object> processor;
    if (typeMapping.TryGetValue(x.ExtractType, out processor)
        processor(iniConfig);
    else
        Error(iniConfig);
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
FilesToProcess.ForEach(InvokeProcessor);
```

Easy to read and understand. Also faster because the dictionary will only be searched once for each file.

### Edit

Alright, if you really wanna use that weird `iif()` thing, here's how to fix it:

```
object iif(bool expression, Func<object> truePart, Func<object> falsePart)
    { return expression ? truePart() : falsePart(); }
```

...and how to use it:

```
FilesToProcess.ForEach(x => iif(
    typeMapping.ContainsKey(x.ExtractType), 
    () => typeMapping[x.ExtractType](x), 
    () => Error(x)));
```

Basically the evaluation of the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> argument of `iif()` is delayed until one of them is actually needed. In your previous version all arguments were evaluated before the execution of `iff()` resulting in a call to the dictionary indexer *and* to `Error()` every time a `IniConfig` object was processed.

A word of warning though: if you use this in production then harakiri might be your only way out of the devastating shame that will overcome you a couple years later.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of this over just doing the foreach loop directly though IF it can't all be done with a ternary inline to .ForEach().

Comment: @user441521, well then do a normal `foreach` loop. I think this is more readable, but maybe it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @user441521, I edited the answer to fix your problem with `iif`.

Comment: This looks like it might be asking for a dictionary extension that does something similar. Provide what you want to do when they key is there and all is good and provide an error function when it's not. No need to trap the exception then and it can continue processing. Not sure yet how to get there.

Comment: @user441521, I don't think you can generalize this use case into something reusable.

Comment: Actually I just made an extension to dictionaries where this is possible which is generic: FilesToProcess.ForEach(x =>
                typeMapping.TryTest(
                    () => typeMapping[x.ExtractType](x),
                    () => Error(x)
                )
            );

Comment: @user441521, it seems like there is something missing. How does the `TryTest()` know which of the two lambdas it should run if it doesn't know `x.ExtractType`?

Comment: in the extension the first lambda is ran no matter what. this is the part that you want to do your logic and you make the assumption that the key exists. That call is inside a try/catch in the extension. If that fails (say because the key didn't exist or any other reason) then it'll run the second lambda which is the error lambda. It's different than the iif where the user has to check the key and then decide. It just says use it as if the key exists and let the try/catch be the thing that controls the flow.

Comment: This is the usage that I prefer. I don't want to check if the key exists. I just want to use it and if it doesn't exist I have an error option if I want to handle it. Maybe I don't want to handle it so that part could be null (have to test that)

Comment: @user441521, ok I see. But apart from being less readable this will also be slow if there are a lot of unknown keys, because you are using exceptions for control flow (which is a big no-no, actually).

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal. I'm ALL about usage of a language though, when dreaming, and this pattern of just use the dictionary and worry about if a key doesn't exist in a chained error() function I think is better usage vs pre-checking. I'm not using it in production, just dreaming and a coding challenge to get the usage style working.